# Is using "assai" in Italian considered vulgar language?

Tags: regional, etymology

My conversation manual included the word *assai* very often as an equivalent for *troppo*, *molto*, etc. When I got in Italy one of my friends from there, of Neapolitan origin, said that is a Neapolitan word, not used in Italian and it is considered *vulgar* to use it, because of its peasant connotations. I heard it numerous times on TV and the shows weren't about history/ethnology, but nowadays subjects. Also other friends from Veneto didn't knew its meaning. So what's the story with this word?

Comment: Your friends don't know Italian, I'm afraid. It's true that in Veneto the word is not frequently used, though; but from not using it to not understanding it, there's a big jump.

Comment: Interesting. I majored in Spanish/Linguistics and am now tackling Italian; which is naturally what brought me here. This is interestingly not disimilar from the use of "harto" in Spanish. Absolutely a word that can be used correctly to mean sort of like "had enough/sick of" [Estoy harto del frío- I'm sick of the cold]. Many speakers also use it like "a lot/ma you" [harto gente- a lot of of people; or assai persone] but it's not really correct. Still, in my experience very elitist wealthy whites in South America scoff at it as if "it would be unimaginable in an interview" but in reality it's co

Comment: It’s so vulgar that it is used dozen of times in Dante Alighieri’s _Commedia_! (:-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your friend is wrong when he says that this word is a regionalism. It is usually used as an adverb meaning "much, very", intended to reinforce an adjective:

> assai bello = very beautiful

It may also be used in the sense of "many" in front of a noun (so, taking the value of an adjective). Beware, it's an old usage, mostly considered wrong nowadays (except than probably in the South):

> assai persone = many people

Moreover, a third usage exists. You can indeed use it to mean "much" as an adverb:

> Ho fatto assai per te = I did much for you

All this is perfectly fine in Italian (and that's why you hear it very often).

This said, I understand (a bit) what your friend meant. In Naples and the neighborhood, the word is used *after* an adjective (in the same sense outlined in my first example here), and this is a regional usage. It is anyway wrong to say that it does not exist in Italia. If the one from Veneto didn't know the word, it's his/her fault.

As for the etymology, the word comes from *ad satis*, Latin, meaning "enough" and indeed its original meaning has been shifted from "enough, in a sufficient way" to "much" ([you can read the Italian etymology dictionary here](http://www.etimo.it/?term=assai)).

Comment: I have never heard 'ci sono *assai persone*', except in Naples and around there, though.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Treccani (here http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/assai/), cites Machiavelli with this usage, I'm not sure it's so common but I'm also not sure it's related to Naples as well.

Comment: *assai* sounds *really* south-like, at least to my friulan ear. In the North it's almost never used. This doesn't mean that it is a regionalism, but sure the frequency of its usage changes quite a lot between regions.

Comment: Un uso raro (non so se corretto), di cui ho sentito solo una volta, è "assai" usato da solo, sempre col significato originale di "è abbastanza". Per es. ti sto versando del cibo nel piatto, e mi dici "assai" intendendo "è abbastanza, puoi smettere".

Comment: @Lohoris Io non l'ho mai sentito usato in quel modo, non credo che sia corretto comunque.

Comment: "Assai persone" sounds *disgusting* to my ears, if it is not a gag of some comedian from the Zelig TV show. I would never say that not even under torture!

Comment: Machiavelli might have said "assai persone", but he lived some 500 years ago. :)

Comment: @RickyRobinson Right, answer edited

Comment: I never heard "assai persone". It is definitely wrong.

Comment: I live in Lombardy and I use *assai* as an adverb (never as an adjective) pretty often. It's a bit unusual but definitely not wrong nor vulgar. It may actually sound a bit bookish or even posh in the Northern half of the country.

Comment: Besides Machiavelli, Dante Alighieri can be cited for the use of “assai” as an adjective, for example in _Inf._ XXIII, 143 (“E ‘l frate: «Io udi’ già dire a Bologna / del diavol vizi assai, tra’ quali udi’ / ch’elli è bugiardo e padre di menzogna».”).

Answer (score 16):

What on Earth makes them think it is “vulgar”? It is a regular, non-regional Italian word (it appears in Petrarca, Leopardi etc. and is used for instance even in musical notation: *allegro assai* etc.). As for many words, it is used more or less in different parts of Italy (or, for other words, in different strata of population, or by different age groups): this are matters studied by sociolinguistics.

A point to be careful about: Its original meaning is *enough* (from Latin *ad satis*), but it has been used for centuries in the sense of “much, very.”

(As always happens for the meaning of single words, most of the story can be read in [the relevant article of any good dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/assai/).)

Answer (score 8):

*Assai* is a sort of superlative and it is absolutely not vulgar. It comes from the Latin word *satis*, which means *very* or *much* depending on the usage. In Southern Italy, it is often used as an adverb with the same meaning. For example:

*[Correct usage]* Un uomo assai famoso (*A very famous man*.)
*[Southern Italian usage]* Io ho mangiato assai. (*I ate too much*.)

TL;DR: No, it's not vulgar.

Answer (score 7):

I am going to get downvotes for this, but I feel the need to warn you.

My advice is to use *assai* only in written language (in sentences like "un uomo assai famoso", citing [LiquidFiber](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1494/340), or "un locale assai noto e frequentato"), and *as little as possible*. If you use it, do follow [LiquidFiber](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1494/340)'s advice.

In the spoken, everyday language it may appear:

1. Contrived and 'acted' ("fa assai caldo oggi", most likely reaction: "what?")
2. A regionalism, even if it is not (already discussed)
3. Funny (because of 2)

The upvote-catching answer is: yes, you can use it, it's on the dictionary. But if I were a close friend of yours I would say you: avoid it! I can hardly imagine a job interview in Milan or in Florence where the candidate says *assai*. So embarrassing.

Comment: I would be delighted if in a job interview (which is something I sometimes do) I heard a candidate express him/herself in good Italian, correctly using words like _assai_. BTW, I'm from Rome, which is north of the line where _assai_ is used in "regional" ways.

Comment: That's why one should probably hope to have someone like you as the interviewer! :) However, you can't be always that lucky. Better safe than sorry...

Comment: It may be awkward in speech for precisely the opposite reason than being vulgar. :-)

Answer (score 1):

***Assai*** is not a vulgar word. It is and old-fashioned word though, which was *mainly used in poetry*. Sometimes, is also used in *southern/central Italy* as part of local dialects, but even in this case, it's not vulgar at all. It is just an old-fashioned way to make a superlative (as others pointed out).

Comment: I'm not sure "mainly used in poetry" is correct.

Comment: You are right, i needed to better explain what i meant. By it is "mainly used in poetry" i wanted to underline that it is very old fashioned. Moreover, it mostly belongs to some specific regions of italy, and its use nowadays is quite rare. 

thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

I think *assai* is fine used conversationally to mean "much/very" as described by several people above. Certainly it is used in this way in Lazio, Tuscany and Emilia-Romagna.

It has a more poetic, old-fashioned tone when used adverbially or adjectivally *after* the expression/word it is qualifying, which is more common in the south, esp. Naples.

In Neapolitan, it is "assaje", as in the very famous folk song "*Te voglio bene assaje*", referenced in Lucio Dalla's song "*Caruso*".

Showing you have a knowledge and awareness of this part of Italian heritage would be impressive to your Italian friends, if they are not too ignorant to know it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great word, and I have been endeavoring to get to know it better. It sounds very similar to the French word, "assez" (pronounced "assAY"), meaning "enough", and a link someone above posted about its etymology confirms this. The south of Italy was long an outpost of French influence (see Wikipedia on "Southern Italy"), so it is not surprising that the word is used more there.

It doesn't seem like a vulgar word to me, but I wonder whether when some people say that it is, what they mean is that it is not highbrow, "proper" Italian, but colloquial street language primarily of working people. The root of the word, vulgar, does not have to do, incidentally, with being profane or rude, but simply common.

The character of this expression is, from what I can tell, essentially one that is focused on emphasizing something by deliberate understatement - like when people say, "Enough!" but really they mean that much more than enough has been said. I've often heard it used as a stand alone word. "Assai..." plus some raised eyebrows... meaning, suggestively, "a *L O T*..."., It's a much more suggestive word than "molto", which has a sort of prosaic, numerical quality.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! *Assai* is not vulgar, and it is standard Italian (it is true it is used more often in the South, but it's not unheard of in the North either). It is indeed a cognate of *assez*, but like the French equivalent it is often used also in formal prose.

Answer (score -1):

Caruso by Lucio Dalla
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlQsZ.png)

In the lyrics of the song in the image I posted, you will see "assai"

This is not vulgar. My nonna uses it often to mean "a lot," "a great deal," etc. My nonna is Calabrese and my other Sicilian nonni understand her usage of it. It is not limited to Lazio and Tuscany etc. In usage.

Comment: Notice that the lyrics of that song, while not actually in Neapolitan dialect, hint at it and contain several non-standard Italian terms and uses (such as *te* for *ti*, *dint'* for *dentro*) etc., so perhaps it is not the best text to ascertain the use of *assai* in standard Italian. (By the way, *sai* is a whole different word, meaning “you know”.)